# Twitter web app which stores and displays tweets

Tags: linux, web-apps, twitter

My problem is that I have a Twitter account with about 50 feeds I've subscribed. When I don't have an Internet connection, I can only retrieve 1000 last tweets (I use [Plume](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelup.touiteur) for Android). Twitter limits the number of tweets anyone can retrieve, so I can't use any Twitter reader which doesn't save tweets.

I'm looking for a software than I can install on a Linux (Debian) server. I want it to store my Twitter feed (the software should be launched automatically every hour for example) and display them in a Web interface (even I have not checked it for several days). A nice function would be to mark tweets as read, so I can browse the app later and only see new tweets.

Currently, I just can't find any software because all my searches which include *Twitter* give me unrelated results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've developed my own software that fits my needs: [AsyncTweets](https://github.com/alexislefebvre/AsyncTweets). It's a PHP5 application built with Symfony2, Doctrine2 and a few packages available from Composer.